# Object is of type 'unknown' error while setting data in react d3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to set up a custom hook that fetches data, does some manipulations on the data and returns the manipulated data in a react d3 application. The data `type` is

```
interface EventViewerDataTypes {
    date: string
    site: string
    type: string
    value: string
}[]
```

Inside the `useEffect` hook there is an error `Object is of type 'unknown'.`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { json, timeParse } from "d3"

const parseTime = timeParse("%d-%m-%Y")

interface EventViewerDataTypes {
  date: string
  site: string
  type: string
  value: string
}[]
export const useData = (jsonUrl: string) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<EventViewerDataTypes | null>(null)
  useEffect(() => {
       json(jsonUrl).then((data) => {
           data.forEach((d) => {
                d.date = parseTime(d.date)
                d.value = +d.value
            })
            setData(data)
        })
    }, [])
    return data
}
```

I'm a bit struggling with `typescript` and any help, or recommendations would be valuable.

**Update**

With the help of `Robby Cornelissen`, I made some progress and updated the code, and still some issues. So I tried updating the `EventViewerDataTypes` as

```
interface EventViewerDataTypes {
    date: string | Date | null
    site: string
    type: string
    value: string | number
}[]
```

But still have some errors

```
json<EventViewerDataTypes[]>(jsonUrl).then((data) => {
    data?.forEach((d) => {

        // Error!
        d.date = parseTime(d.date) 
        // Argument of type 'string | Date | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

        d.value = +d.value
    })

    // Error!
    //Argument of type 'EventViewerDataTypes[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<EventViewerDataTypes | null>'
     setData(data) 

})
```

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sorry regarding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code:

##### Untyped JSON response

There is no way for the TypeScript compiler to infer what type will be retrieved from the `jsonUrl`.

According to the [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-fetch/index.d.ts), the `json()` function has a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) that lets you specify the expected return type, so this should fix it:

```
json<EventViewerDataTypes>(jsonUrl).then((data) => {
  /* ... */
});
```

##### Handling of an `undefined` JSON response

Since from the type definition it seems that the `json()` function can also return `undefined`, you might also need to use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (or an `if`-check) before looping over `data`:

```
data?.forEach((d) => {
  /* ... */
});
```

In case the `setData(data)` function you call after doesn't accept `undefined`, you're probably better off with an explicit `if`-check and either calling `setData(null)` or not calling `setData()` at all.

##### Discrepancies between JSON types and model types

There are discrepancies between the JSON data you retrieve, and the way you wish to model them in your application. First of all, it's more readable and convenient to type a single `EventViewerDataType` object (instead of `EventViewerDataTypes`), and then use `EventViewerDataType[]` whenever you need an array.

Based on your processing logic, this is how I think `EventViewerDataType` should be typed:

```
interface EventViewerDataType {
  date: Date | null;
  site: string;
  type: string;
  value: number;
}
```

Then, since your JSON seems to contain only strings, I would use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to define the data transfer object as:

```
type StringValues<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string;
}
```

Then, in your processing logic, instead of using `forEach()`, use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map from your JSON format objects (`StringValues<EventViewerDataType>[]`) to your model objects (`EventViewerDataType[]`).